# Login script issue with database

Tags: php, mysql, authentication

I wrote a login script for a website that I am building using resources I have found online.  When I ran my code on a local server it worked fine but now that I am actually running it online on a real server it doesn't work.  I think I have narrowed down my error but with being new to PHP and not having prior experience with MySql I can't really fix my problem.  This is the file for the login script:

```
  //login file
<?php
class Login{
    private $db_connection = null;

    public function __construct(){
        session_start();
        $this->dologinWithPostData();
    }

    private function dologinWithPostData(){

             $this->db_connection = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASSWORD, DB_NAME);

            if (!$this->db_connection()->connect_errno) {

                // escape the POST stuff
                $email = $_POST['email'];
                // database query, getting all the info of the selected user (allows login via email address in the
                // username field)
                $sql = "SELECT email, password
                        FROM users
                        WHERE email = '" . $email ."'";

                $result_of_login_check = $this->db_connection->query($sql);//This is 0

                // if this user exists
                if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {
                    // get result row (as an object)
                    $result_row = $result_of_login_check->fetch_object();
                    // using PHP 5.5's password_verify() function to check if the provided password fits
                    // the hash of that user's password
                    if ($_POST['password'] == $result_row->password) {
                        // write user data into PHP SESSION (a file on your server)
                        $_SESSION['email'] = $result_row->email;
                        $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 1;
                    } else {
                        $this->errors[] = "Wrong password. Try again.";
                        $_SESSION['user_login_status'] = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = "Database connection problem.";
            }
        }

    print_r($this->errors);
    }

    public function isUserLoggedIn()
    {
        if (isset($_SESSION['user_login_status']) AND $_SESSION['user_login_status'] == 1) {
            return true;
        }
        // default return
        return false;
    }
}

?>
```

I run it in another file that is essentially the following:

```
//Run file
require_once("dbconfig.php");
    include_once("login.php");
    $login = new Login();
    if($login->isUserLoggedIn() == true){
    //go to another page }
```

The variables used to access the database are instantiated in `dbconfig.php` and are correct.  With this code I get an error that says the page is not working and is unable to handle the request.  When I comment out the line

```
if (!$this->db_connection()->connect_errno) {
```

and the else statement following it, the output is "This user does not exist".  So I think the error has something to do with `$this->db_connection()->connect_errno)`.  If you can find where I went wrong or have any advice on how to rewrite the script to make it better, it is greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are vulnerable to [sql injection attacks](http://bobby-tables.com)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: No no no! You _never_ store user passwords in a database. You don't. What you store is _a hash of the user password_, one created by a _good_ hashing algorithm. Then, at login time, you hash the provided password and _compare both hashes_. That way you don't risk exposing user passwords if your service is compromised.

Comment: SQL injection and storing passwords aside, can you try setting `error_reporting(E_ALL)` and [edit] your post to include any PHP log messages it generates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a database establishing error your live remote server database configuration is different.Please verify you `dbconfig.php` file make sure 
database name, host , port , username , password are well defined with your live database

Answer (score 1):

This is wrong:

```
        if (!$this->db_connection()->connect_errno) {
```

`db_connection` is simply a variable containing your DB connection object. It is **NOT** a method.

You probably want

```
        if (!$this->db_connection->connect_errno) {
                                 ^--note lack of ()
```

instead.

Answer (score 0):

I think issue with this follwoing check. your result gets more than 1 records.
// if this user exists

```
if ($result_of_login_check->num_rows == 1) {
......
}else{
    $this->errors[] = "This user does not exist.";
}
```

make sure your email address is unique in Data table, if it is not unique then your above statement will fail and show the text "This user does not exist." from else part